# C# Set date property as maximum data of another property

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to have a class where one property, when getting, returns the maximum value of another property.

Below's my class

```
public class Transaction {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceNumber { get;set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LatestTransactionDate {
        get {
            // return max of TransactionDate in the list/DbSet
        }
    }
    public int DayDifference {
        get {
            return (LatestTransactionDate - TransactionDate).TotalDays;
        }
    }
    public string TransactionCategory {
        if (DayDifference <= 180) {
            return "Category 1";
        } else if (DayDifference > 180 && DayDifferene <= 240) {
            return "Category 2";
        } ... so on and so forth...
    }
    public string TransactionSubCategory {
        if (TransactionCategory == "Category 1") {
            return "SubCategory 1";
        } else if ...

        ... you get the idea...

    }
    //... and a whole lot more properties that are dependent on LatestTransactionDate and DayDifference with their varying calculation requirements
}
```

Reason for this is, I want to calculate the difference in days **(DayDifference)** between a transaction and the latest transaction. So first, I want to get the latest dated transaction then from there calculate the DayDifference of every transaction.

I would be dealing with millions of records that grows by the month.

EDIT: I added more properties to provide more details of what is to be expected of my model and how other properties are dependent on **LatestTransactionDate** and **DayDifference**.

I'm hoping to do this within my model so that it is calculated on-the-fly whenever I get my Transactions DbSet (see below) and no need to do lambda whenever I pull it up. Then every other properties are also calculated accordingly.

```
var allTransactions = _dbSet.Transactions.ToListAsync()
```

I hoping **NOT** to do below (just to reiterate):

```
var latestTransactionDate = _dbSet.Transactions.Select(txn => txn.TransactionDate).Max();
```

Would really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: this is really bad design imo, create service that gets max date and reuse it in your scope whenever it is needed

Comment: @tmsbrndz how do i get the maximum TransactionDate and use it as my return value for LatestTransactionDate?

Comment: @Yegor Androsov I was hoping to put this in one place i.e. my model, so I don't have to create a separate service just to calculate the maximum date everytime I pull my fetch my transaction list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and comments makes me think you are not familiar with Dependency Injection and how easily it can be used within .NET/ASP.NET Core application. The code you want to have should definitely be moved to separate service and injected as dependency

Regarding `TransactionCategory` and other calculated properties. Business logic should be moved out of models to a service that fills in these fields for all items. It can inject `TransactionService` similar to one in the code below to get max date to calculate difference.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    // Basic model
    public class Transaction
    {
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    }

    // db context mock to emulate EF
    public class DbContextMock
    {
        public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; }

        public DbContextMock()
        {
            Transactions = new List<Transaction>();

            Transactions.Add(new Transaction()
            {
                TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
            });
            Transactions.Add(new Transaction()
            {
                TransactionDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
            });
            Transactions.Add(new Transaction()
            {
                TransactionDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
            });
        }
    }

    // service that stores max transaction date in scope
    public class TransactionService
    {
        private readonly DbContextMock dbContext;

        public TransactionService(DbContextMock dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        private DateTime? _maxTransactionDate;
        public DateTime GetMaxTransactionDate()
        {
            if (!_maxTransactionDate.HasValue)
            {
                _maxTransactionDate = dbContext.Transactions.Select(x => x.TransactionDate).Max();
            }

            return _maxTransactionDate.Value;
        }
    }

    // 2 services that use max date to produce some results
    public class SomeServiceA
    {
        private readonly TransactionService transactionService;

        public SomeServiceA(TransactionService transactionService)
        {
            this.transactionService = transactionService;
        }

        public void CalculateSomething()
        {
            var maxDate = transactionService.GetMaxTransactionDate();

            // do something
        }
    }

    public class SomeServiceB
    {
        private readonly TransactionService transactionService;

        public SomeServiceB(TransactionService transactionService)
        {
            this.transactionService = transactionService;
        }

        public void DoSomethingElse()
        {
            var maxDate = transactionService.GetMaxTransactionDate();

            // do something
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            serviceCollection.AddScoped<DbContextMock>();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<TransactionService>();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<SomeServiceA>();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<SomeServiceB>();

            using var scope = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(); // if you are using asp.net core, scope is created per request

            var serviceA = scope.GetService<SomeServiceA>(); // create service with a single line

            serviceA.CalculateSomething();

            var serviceB = scope.GetService<SomeServiceB>();

            serviceB.DoSomethingElse();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a pretty horrible design, but you could inject the `DbContext` (in EF Core) in the entity's constructor, and use it on the actual property.

Something like:

```
public class Transaction {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceNumber { get;set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LatestTransactionDate { get; init; }
    public int DayDifference {
        get {
            return (LatestTransactionDate - TransactionDate).TotalDays
        }
    }

    public Transaction() {} // <-- to allow other `new` when not materialized by EF
    public Transaction(MyDbContext context) {
      LatestTransactionDate = context.Transactions.Select(txn => txn.TransactionDate).Max();
    }
}
```

Again, this is horrible design (and would roundtrip to the database on every single `Transaction` item materialization), but hey, it answers your question :-)

If you go this way (which I do not recommend), then I'd probably store the `DbContext` on a private property with a setter (in case you change the entity to a different `DbContext`, EF Core updates the property too), and calculate the value there (change the `init` on the property to a proper `private set`, etc).

Or you may want to store the `DbContext` and calculate the property value on the property getter (that'd work if you have long-lived contexts).

But the way to go for this would be having a service that gives you that data, not have it on the entity itself.

PS: if I was going to do it this way *(which I wouldn't)*, I'd probably have a trigger on the database and have an actual column on the table which would get updated (with a simple `SELECT MAX()` query) everytime an insert or update happens, and not solve this at the Entity Framework level

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. yeah it is tempting but sounds too much to pass the entire context again and again... especially that i would be dealing with millions of records... (i should [and will] add this piece of info in the main post) is my "requirement" even possible to do? :`(

by the way, we are doing a code-first approach so i'm not sure a trigger would be feasible.

Comment: Code-first on EF always involves migrations, and you can do a custom migration that creates a trigger. But again, I'd say this is design is pretty much horrible (you are adding a property to an entity which involves working with the whole set).

If this is all about cosmetics and not wanting to have a service just for this, make an extension method of `DbSet<Transaction>` called `GetLastTransactionDate()` and call it like `context.Transactions.GetLastTransactionDate()` and you don't need an external service class/object (your service object would be the actual `DbSet`).

Comment: You are just putting things where they don't belong (putting a property or calculation on the set, on a single entity object), and trying to hack your way around it. This smells from very far, let me tell you :-)